# Attempted to wrap undefined property findOneAndUpdate as function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I wrote a unit test for my `PUT /cars/:id` using `Sinon.js`:
unitTest.js:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Monck mongodb Models
require('sinon-mongoose');

const Car = require('../../models/Car');
describe('PUT /cars/:id', () => {
        it('Should update a car successfully', (done) => {
            const updateBody = {
                name: 'new car name',
            }
            const CarMock = sinon.mock(new Car(updateBody));
            const car = CarMock.object;
            const expectedResult = {    
                statusCode: 200
            }
            const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
            CarMock.expects('findOneAndUpdate').withArgs(id).yields(null, expectedResult);
            car.findOneAndUpdate(id, updateBody, (error, res) => {
                if (error) done(error)
                CarMock.verify();
                CarMock.restore();
                expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            })
        })
})
```

when I run the test I got this error:

```
     PUT /cars/:id
       Should update a car successfully:
 TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property findOneAndUpdate as function
  at wrapMethod (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\util\core\wrap-method.js:72:21)
  at Object.expects (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\mock.js:71:13)
  at Object.mock.expects (node_modules\sinon-mongoose\dist\index.js:49:37)
  at Context.it (server\test\cars\unitTests.js:106:29)
```

What's the mistake I hade made when writing this test?

Comment: Probably shouldn't be a space between CarMock and .object on the line that says `const car = CarMock .object;`

Comment: @JSONaLeo it's just a typo error when I wrote the question. I don't have spaces between the name and the property

Comment: What do you get if you log `console.log(id)` after assigning it to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`? I think you may need to pass in an ID string as an argument to that function

Comment: `console.log(id)` returns `5caa1fe8a74a06002074f62a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution to pass the test I update the code to be:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Monck mongodb Models
require('sinon-mongoose');

const Car = require('../../models/Car');
describe('PUT /cars/:id', () => {
        it('Should update a car successfully', (done) => {
            const updateBody = {
                name: 'new car name',
            }
            const CarMock = sinon.mock(Car);
            const car = CarMock.object;
            const expectedResult = {    
                statusCode: 200
            }
            const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
            CarMock.expects('findOneAndUpdate').withArgs({_id: id}, updateBody).yields(null, expectedResult);
            car.findOneAndUpdate(id, updateBody, (error, res) => {
                if (error) done(error)
                CarMock.verify();
                CarMock.restore();
                expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            })
        })
})
```